# Electron Builder excluding nested node_modules

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, node-modules, electron-builder

I am using electron-builder 22.6.0 to create mas build but .app file does not include nested node_modules (node_modules of myApp). I have tried using extraFiles in package.json it creates a folder in Resources and copy all the node_modules in that but still getting 404.

My package.json:

```
"extraResources": [
  {
    "from": "path/node_modules",
    "to": "path/node_modules",
    "filter": [
      "**/*"
    ]
  }
],
```

Folder structure:

```
---root
    --package.json
    --node_modules
    --myApp
       --package.json
       --node_modules
```

How can I include node_modules by default? My electron version is 8.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electron-builder will pack the `node_modules` by removing the dev node dependencies and unused modules. We don't need to do this manually.

If you still want to include this in your package, add this to your electron-builder configuration:
`"files": ["node_modules/**/*"]`